# Unit tangent, principal normal and their cross product form an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, cross-product

Suppose $\mathbf{T}(s)$ is the unit tangent vector to a curve parametrized by arclength, and $\mathbf{N}(s) = \mathbf{T}'(s)/||\mathbf{T}'(s)||$ assuming $\mathbf{T}(s) \ne \mathbf{0}$.

> Define the binormal vector $\mathbf{B}(s)=\mathbf{T}(s)\times \mathbf{N}(s)$. Then $\left\{\mathbf{T}(s),\mathbf{N}(s),\mathbf{B}(s)\right\}$ forms a right handed orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I see they are orthogonal, but why are they basis? I feel like I'm missing a basic fact about cross products probably.

Comment: You have three linearly independent vectors in a three dimensional vector space.

Comment: I'm unable to see the "clearly linearly independent" bit @JohnDouma. I haven't done linear algebra for a while. Could you spell it out for me please?

Comment: If $a\mathbf B+b\mathbf T+c\mathbf N=\mathbf 0$ then what do $a$, $b$ and $c$ equal?

Comment: @JohnDouma I thought we could give B,T,N arbitrary coordinates then conclude $a=b=c=0$ is the only solution. I'm guessing there's a way to see more readily? Rather than say calculating a determinant before using the conditions on B,T,N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever we have $3$ orthogonal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, they form a basis if and only if each of them is non-null. But you are assuming that $\mathbf{T}(s)\neq0$, $\bigl\lVert\mathbf{N}(s)\bigr\rVert=1$ and the cross-product of two non-null orthogonal vectors is never $0$.

Comment: Thank you response.